# How to assign default values for ext based properties in gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am working on a gradle plugin with a task where it accesses the extra params using the project object itself like

```
project.extraParam1
project.extraParam2
```

Now I can use this plugin from another project and pass the parameters in the build.gradle file as

```
ext {
  extraParam1 value1
  extraParam2 value2
}
```

I mean I apply this plugin in another project's build.gradle. Define the ext parameters and call the plugin task and it works. The task is able to access the extra properties. However, I want to set some default values to these, so that even though the project which is using the plugin doesn't define the ext parameter, it has some default values and works for default values.

Comment: You can set the values in the plugin. Could you please share the whole `build.gradle` that illustrates what you want to achieve?

Comment: I know that this won't solve this specific problem, but extra properties should not be used for plugins. Instead, you should rely on extension or convention properties.

Answer (score 5):

In your plugin, you can do something like that :

```
def extraParam1 = project.hasProperty('extraParam1') ? project.extraParam1 : 'default value'
```

Comment: You can use findProperty method with elvis operator. findProperty  will return a null value when the property doesn't exists, and its value if it exists. It's a shorter expression.
`def extraParam1 = project.findProperty('extraParam1') ?: 'default value'`